# MariaDB Measured value JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mariadb, json-extract

I am new to the forum and have a question. I query the MySQL database like this:
SELECT DISTINCT concat (value) FROM mqtt
WHERE topic LIKE 'Sens/005/pulse/SENSOR' AND date(ts)=curdate()
ORDER BY ts DESC

Result:

```
{"Time":"2021-06-02T13:15:10","AM2301":{"Temperature":26.7,"Humidity":40.6,"DewPoint":12.2},"ESP32":{"Temperature":55.6},"TempUnit":"C"}
{"Time":"2021-06-02T13:10:10","AM2301":{"Temperature":26.7,"Humidity":40.8,"DewPoint":12.3},"ESP32":{"Temperature":55.0},"TempUnit":"C"}
{"Time":"2021-06-02T13:05:10","AM2301":{"Temperature":26.6,"Humidity":41.0,"DewPoint":12.2},"ESP32":{"Temperature":55.6},"TempUnit":"C"}
{"Time":"2021-06-02T13:00:10","AM2301":{"Temperature":26.6,"Humidity":41.3,"DewPoint":12.4},"ESP32":{"Temperature":55.0},"TempUnit":"C"}
{"Time":"2021-06-02T12:55:10","AM2301":{"Temperature":26.6,"Humidity":41.5,"DewPoint":12.4},"ESP32":{"Temperature":55.0},"TempUnit":"C"}
{"Time":"2021-06-02T12:50:10","AM2301":{"Temperature":26.7,"Humidity":41.8,"DewPoint":12.6},"ESP32":{"Temperature":55.0},"TempUnit":"C"}
```

Is it possible in MySQL to output only the last value 26.7 as temperature (for Grafana)? eg. JSON_EXTRACT ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions need to be asked in English

Comment: can u help me please? Thanks